# Kmap, 4 variables

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

I have a question about 4 variables Kmap.  We get used to the ones with 2 variables at the column and 2 variables on the row, just like the ones below.

[image]

**I am wondering if we can have 3 variables at the column and 1 variable at the row?**

Comment: Sure, just try it with your example. You just have to know what patterns are considered adjacent and belong together logically. (Like in the current diagram, the corners are considered adjacent.)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_8/11.html
I think you will find it useful. Just think of the map as a building, now you are looking at the ground floor... What if you name that floor "zero" and add a floor above it and name it "one"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with having more than 2 variables in an axis is that terms that have a single bit difference are no longer adjacent to each other, which makes interpretation more difficult. This is why (2-dimensional) Karnaugh maps usually have no more than 2 variables per axis and no more than 4 variables per "slice".